# Make a htaccess file which will give redirect to child folder index page

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to make a htaccess file which will give redirect to child folder index page

```
My Structure

ROOT FOLDER
  CHILD FOLDER
  htaccess
```

How to make control flow to CHILD/index.php with htaccess file, when `http:\\localhost\root\` is browser ?

I have an `test.php` inside child folder(child\test.php).

I want avoid the accessing of php file in browser, when user tried in this link `http:\\localhost\root\child\test.php`. Please help me, how to solve it ?  Even change of folder structure is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If the user attempts to go to `http:\\localhost\root\` you want it to redirect to `http:\\localhost\root\child\index.php`?

```
#Make sure url rewriting is turned on
RewriteEngine on
#if the user attempts to access the index.php file, then redirec them to the test.php file.
Redirect 301 index.php /child/test.php
```

Comment: Yes, redirect to  `http:\\localhost\root\child\index.php`. Then **test.php** is pure **php** file, there is no chance user go in `http:\\localhost\root\child\test.php`. But in order to provide security, I want to avoid it's direct access, which is similar to in  cake php framework, where the controllers can't be accessed.

Comment: @Zim3r - you want to redirect every php file to a sub-folder? `RewriteRule ^(([^/]+)\.php) /subfolder/$1 [R=301,L]` This will move every php file that is not in a sub-folder (real or virtual) and redirect the user to the subfolder with the same file path (e.g. abc.com/page-x.php => abc.com/subfolder/page-x.php)